# Excel how to convert weeknum to date when crossing the year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dayofweek, week-number

I have a table with Date column and weeknum column.

[image]

The weeknum column has below formula to create a srting: 2022/10.
`=YEAR([@[Date]})&"/"&WEEKNUM([@[Date]],2)`

I would like to get the start day and end day of the week converting from the string "2022/10".

I tried `=DATE($M$1,1,-2)-(WEEKDAY(DATE($M$1,1,3))+(MID(M4,6,2)*7))` where `$M$1` references current year and `M4` references Year/ weeknum but it returns 10/17/2021. It should return 2/28/2022, and as the weeknumber increases. the returned dates decrease.
The dates of 2021/53 are correct, but the others got wrong.

[image]

How do I get fixed the dates?

Comment: Does this help ... https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/04/29/excel-weeknum-function-convert-week-number-date/

Comment: @Skin I actually used the method in the website, but it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by taking the weekday number of the date away from itself and adding 7-weekday to itself.

i.e.

If we use the first date on your list and we say weeks start on Monday:

**The first day of the week (Monday)** = E2-WEEKDAY(E2,2)+1 = 12/27/21

**The last day of the week (Sunday)** = E2+(7-WEEKDAY(E2,2)) = 01/02/22

Note: I have assumed your first date (12/27/2021) is in Cell E2

If you want Sunday to be the first day of the week, simply add a 1 instead of a 2 into the WEEKDAY part of the formula.